# How do I check if the system is currently suspended?

Tags: suspend, sleep, armbian

I want to use my orange pi power button to suspend and resume system and have some troubles with check state. So I wrote shell script for this but it won't work; it's only suspending.

When I click the button in suspend mode, the resumed and suspends again in a few seconds. I can't find a way to resume it.

It seems likely that `systemctl is-system-running` is returning `running` in the suspended state. My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
VALID_P=`systemctl is-system-running`
echo $VALID_P
if [ "$VALID_P" = "running" ]; then
    systemctl suspend
else
    systemctl default
fi
```

Comment: If the system is suspended, would `systemctl` return anything, or even run?

Comment: when i executing "systemctl suspend" from suspended system, it awake system for a few sec and make it suspend again

Comment: How do you do that if the system is suspended?

Comment: it is hardware button connected to GPIO of my Orange Pi that execute script above when pressed

Comment: So, when you press the button, the system un-suspends, runs the script which finds out that the system is now not suspended, and then, because the system is not suspended, suspends it again. What's the question?

Comment: If the system is suspended, your script won't run. The system is suspended,  it can't do anything.

Comment: How to make it: 1st click - suspend, 2nd click - resume.

Comment: but how can i resume system from suspend?

Comment: Kusalananda is complitely right. Press the button un-suspends system. Just checked with no actions at button (no script at all). Im suspends system through terminal and just clicked on button - system resumed. Hmmmm... how to make it suspend now lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="/home/pi/loltest"
if [ -e "$file" ]
then
  rm /home/pi/loltest
else
  touch /home/pi/loltest
  systemctl suspend
fi
```

Works OK in armbian. I still have some problems with it in RetroArch or EmulationStation - they just hang after resume.